# Is it possible to use multiple keys for a single element in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing my own function for parsing XML text into objects which is can manipulate and render back into XML text. To handle the nesting, I am allowing XML objects to contain other XML objects as elements.

Since I am automatically generating these XML objects, my plan is to just enter them as elements of a dict as they are created. I was planning on generating an attribute called name which I could use as the key, and having the XML object itself be a value assigned to that key.

All this makes sense to me at this point. But now I realize that I would really like to also save an attribute called `line_number`, which would be the line from the original XML file where I first encountered the object, and there may be some cases where I would want to locate an XML object by `line_number`, rather than by name.

So these are my questions:

1. Is it possible to use a dict in such a way that I could find my XML object *either* by name or by line number? That is, is it possible to have multiple keys assigned to a single value in a dict?
2. How do I do that?
3. If this is a bad idea, what is a better way?

Comment: You can always have multiple keys that map to the same value in a dictionary (in nearly any implementation in nearly any language)- it's multiple values for the same key that you need to work around.

Comment: What do you do if there is more than one tag on a given line?

Comment: XML is not line oriented It can be reformatted without changing the semantics. All you should really care about is the path.

Comment: Have you looked at existing libraries that already do this?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire You're correct that this does not account for multiple lines in XML and Keith you're correct about this in XML. I should have been more clear. I am actually writing a homebrew XML parser because I'm interfacing with a proprietary desktop application, and frankly I don't trust the developers to have implemented XML perfectly. I am trying to cause my script to read and generate XML code that *exactly* matches how it would have looked had I exported it from the desktop application. This is why I decided against using something like ElementTree, because I can't confirm the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. No special magic is required:

```
In [1]: val = object()

In [2]: d = {}

In [3]: d[123] = val

In [4]: d['name'] = val

In [5]: d
Out[5]: {123: <object at 0x23c6d0>, 'name': <object at 0x23c6d0>}
```

I would, however, use two separate dictionaries, one for indexing by name, and one for indexing by line number. Even if the sets of names and line numbers are completely disjoint, I think this is a cleaner design.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_dict['key1'] = my_dict['key2'] = SomeObject
```

should work fine i would think

Answer (score 1):

Since dictionaries can have keys of multiple types, and you are using names (strings only) as one key and numbers (integers only) as another, you can simply make two separate entries point to the same object - one for the number, and one for the string.

`dict[0] = dict['key'] = object1`